# Nuke Chrome's cache and cookies with one click

Tags: chrome

I'm looking for a Chrome extension that will remove all cookies and cache by clicking exactly once on a button, there can not be any dialogs or confirmations. (I need this for development reasons.)

Example of what **I do not** need:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-eraser/gjieilkfnnjoihjjonajndjldjoagffm?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en): *"Clear your cache and browsing data with a single click of a button."*

Comment: I tip my hat to you good sir !